# Route variables received as action variables?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've got the following route configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{project}/{version}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Portal", action = "Index" }
);
```

The idea is to have two custom parameters in the URL, before anything else so an action filter I created can do a few useful things. That works well so far, but here's the problem.

Here's an action method with a parameter called `version`

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod(string version)
{
    //Some logic has been performed using the custom route variable values before getting in here.... 
}
```

If I do the following call: `http:/server/RouteValue1/RouteValue2/MyController/SomeMethod?version=1`

The value of the `version` parameter of `SomeMethod` is `RouteValue2`.

Is there any way to tell the framework not to do that? Keep route variables seperate from action variables ?

Comment: Is that `{project}` and `{version}` are both URL parameters? Also you shouldn't override default route like that - it must have different name and placed on topmost of the route order.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use the same parameter name in both the route config and as a query string. You'll need to rename one, i.e.:

```
http:/server/RouteValue1/RouteValue2/MyController/SomeMethod?ver=1
```